# How can I drop record from pyspark data frame starts with 2K

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using pyspark 3.0.1. I would like to drop rows from column `group` of my pyspark data frame df where records start with `2K`.

My Sample data looks like

```
Name  Age Group
John   23  1L12
Rami   32  2K18
Pat    35  1P28
```

After dropping, my final data frame should look like

```
Name  Age Group
John   23  1L12
Pat    35  1P28
```

Answer (score 1):

Try checking `startswith`:

```
df2 = df.filter(~df.Group.startswith("2K"))
```

Or use `rlike` / `like`:

```
df2 = df.filter(~df.Group.rlike("^2K"))
df2 = df.filter(~df.Group.like("2K%"))
```

Comment: `df2=df.filter(df.Groupe.substr(1, 2) !="2K")`

Answer (score 0):

You can filter using column method `startswith`:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df1 = df.filter(~F.col("Group").startswith("2K"))

df1.show()
#+----+---+-----+
#|Name|Age|Group|
#+----+---+-----+
#|John| 23| 1L12|
#| Pat| 35| 1P28|
#+----+---+-----+
```